# Error when I try to run react-native run-android command

Tags: react-native

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Reactprojects\Makerobos>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 855 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Reactprojects\Makerobos\android\local.properties'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Reactprojects\Makerobos\android\local.properties'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Reactprojects\Makerobos\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Reactprojects\Makerobos\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Reactprojects\Makerobos\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Reactprojects\Makerobos\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SDK path is not correct you need to add a correct path in the below file:
sa
project > android > local.properties

Add the path like below example:

```
sdk.dir = /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
```

After added use the following commands:

```
1. cd android/
2. ./gradlew clean
3. cd ..
4. Command: react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file indexcsasa.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
csacs
5. react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the build fails, but it still runs .Have you tried connecting your app via the WIFI to the remote server? Check the connect via wifi method [React connect via Wifi](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)

I guess that will work