# React-Native Can not build the app using VScode and Android Studio emulatorfirst app

Tags: react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, adb

### Can not build the app using VScode and Android Studio emulator

**adb version**
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.1-5644136

> react-native run-android

PS D:\Projects\React-Native\AwesomeProject> react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'D:\Projects\React-Native\AwesomeProject\android\local.properties'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'D:\Projects\React-Native\AwesomeProject\android\local.properties'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (D:\Projects\React-Native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7
```

Comment: duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061896/error-when-i-try-to-run-react-native-run-android-command

Comment: error is well explained: set your SDK path in environmental settings

Comment: I already set that.. but terminal not recognized that